# Swift 3 - How to cast Real Result<Object> to generic type [T]

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have the following [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) function to fetch all elements from the table in my `Swift 3` app.

```
//Find all elements in the database
func findAll() -> [T] {
   return getRealm().objects(T.self as! Object.Type)
}
```

How do I cast `Result<Object>` from `Realm` to `[T]` in the return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
func findAll<T: Object>() -> [T] {
  return getRealm().objects(T.self).map { $0 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func findAll<T: Object>(type: T.Type) -> [T] {
    return getRealm().objects(type).map { $0 }
}
```